# How to solve error : LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public"?

Tags: c++

I want to make a plugin for a software. In order to make the plugin, I should make a `.dll` file but I  have faced many challenges about making it. My system is Windows 7 and I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 as an IDE. I made a dll project and made two source files, one header file and then I built the solution but I encountered the following errors.

Note : before building the solution, I added the path of include and lib directories of the software.

```
1>     Creating library C:\Users\pars\Desktop\example\FEneohookean\Debug\FEneohookean.lib and object C:\Users\pars\Desktop\example\FEneohookean\Debug\FEneohookean.exp
    1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall FECoreFactory::~FECoreFactory(void)" (??1FECoreFactory@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function __
    1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall FECoreKernel::RegisterClass(class FECoreFactory *)" (?RegisterClass@FECoreKernel@@QAEXPAVFECoreFactory@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall FERegisterClass_T<class FENeoHookeanPI>::FERegisterClass_T<class FENeoHookeanPI>(unsigned int,char const *)" (??0?$FERegisterClass_T@VFENeoHookeanPI@@@@QAE@IPBD@Z)
    1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class FECoreKernel & __cdecl FECoreKernel::GetInstance(void)" (?GetInstance@FECoreKernel@@SAAAV1@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall FERegisterClass_T<class FENeoHookeanPI>::FERegisterClass_T<class FENeoHookeanPI>(unsigned int,char const *)" (??0?$FERegisterClass_T@VFENeoHookeanPI@@@@QAE@IPBD@Z)
    1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall FECoreFactory::FECoreFactory(unsigned int,char const *)" (??0FECoreFactory@@QAE@IPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall FERegisterClass_T<class FENeoHookeanPI>::FERegisterClass_T<class FENeoHookeanPI>(unsigned int,char const *)" (??0?$FERegisterClass_T@VFENeoHookeanPI@@@@QAE@IPBD@Z)
    1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall FEElasticMaterial::FEElasticMaterial(class FEModel *)" (??0FEElasticMaterial@@QAE@PAVFEModel@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall FENeoHookeanPI::FENeoHookeanPI(class FEModel *)" (??0FENeoHookeanPI@@QAE@PAVFEModel@@@Z)
    1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class FEParam * __thiscall FEMaterial::GetParameter(class ParamString const &)" (?GetParameter@FEMaterial@@UAEPAVFEParam@@ABVParamString@@@Z)
    1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall FEMaterial::Serialize(class DumpFile &)" (?Serialize@FEMaterial@@UAEXAAVDumpFile@@@Z)
1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall FEElasticMaterial::SetAttribute(char const *,char const *)" (?SetAttribute@FEElasticMaterial@@UAE_NPBD0@Z)
    1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall FEElasticMaterial::SetAttribute(char const *,char const *)" (?SetAttribute@FEElasticMaterial@@UAE_NPBD0@Z)
    1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall FEMaterial::Properties(void)" (?Properties@FEMaterial@@UAEHXZ)
    1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class FECoreBase * __thiscall FEMaterial::GetProperty(int)" (?GetProperty@FEMaterial@@UAEPAVFECoreBase@@H@Z)
    1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall FEMaterial::FindPropertyIndex(char const *)" (?FindPropertyIndex@FEMaterial@@UAEHPBD@Z)
    1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall FEMaterial::SetProperty(int,class FECoreBase *)" (?SetProperty@FEMaterial@@UAE_NHPAVFECoreBase@@@Z)
    1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual double __thiscall FESolidMaterial::Density(void)" (?Density@FESolidMaterial@@UAENXZ)
    1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall FEElasticMaterial::SetLocalCoordinateSystem(class FEElement &,int,class FEMaterialPoint &)" (?SetLocalCoordinateSystem@FEElasticMaterial@@UAEXAAVFEElement@@HAAVFEMaterialPoint@@@Z)
    1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual double __thiscall FEElasticMaterial::StrainEnergyDensity(class FEMaterialPoint &)" (?StrainEnergyDensity@FEElasticMaterial@@UAENAAVFEMaterialPoint@@@Z)
    1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall FEElasticMaterialPoint::FEElasticMaterialPoint(void)" (??0FEElasticMaterialPoint@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual class FEMaterialPoint * __thiscall FEElasticMaterial::CreateMaterialPointData(void)" (?CreateMaterialPointData@FEElasticMaterial@@UAEPAVFEMaterialPoint@@XZ)
    1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall FEElasticMaterial::~FEElasticMaterial(void)" (??1FEElasticMaterial@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall FENeoHookeanPI::~FENeoHookeanPI(void)" (??1FENeoHookeanPI@@UAE@XZ)
    1>FENeoHookeanPI.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall FEParamContainer::AddParameter(void *,enum FEParamType,int,class RANGE,char const *)" (?AddParameter@FEParamContainer@@IAEXPAXW4FEParamType@@HVRANGE@@PBD@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall FENeoHookeanPI::BuildParamList(void)" (?BuildParamList@FENeoHookeanPI@@MAEXXZ)
    1>FENeoHookeanPI.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall FESolidMaterial::BuildParamList(void)" (?BuildParamList@FESolidMaterial@@MAEXXZ) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall FENeoHookeanPI::BuildParamList(void)" (?BuildParamList@FENeoHookeanPI@@MAEXXZ)
    1>FENeoHookeanPI.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall FEElasticMaterial::Init(void)" (?Init@FEElasticMaterial@@UAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall FENeoHookeanPI::Init(void)" (?Init@FENeoHookeanPI@@UAEXXZ)
    1>FENeoHookeanPI.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class mat3ds __thiscall FEElasticMaterialPoint::LeftCauchyGreen(void)" (?LeftCauchyGreen@FEElasticMaterialPoint@@QAE?AVmat3ds@@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual class mat3ds __thiscall FENeoHookeanPI::Stress(class FEMaterialPoint &)" (?Stress@FENeoHookeanPI@@UAE?AVmat3ds@@AAVFEMaterialPoint@@@Z)
    1>C:\Users\pars\Desktop\example\FEneohookean\Debug\FEneohookean.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 21 unresolved externals
    1>
    1>Build FAILED
```

How can I solve these errors ?

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289170/lnk1120-1-unresolved-externalsand-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol?rq=1) helps

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding the library path to the project setting be sure you also add the required library files(.lib) as an additional dependency for the linker. you can find the additional dependency input field at project->properties->linker->Input and add the actual names(with extension) of the library files separated by a space.